# How do I track down the source of a KVC exception: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key toolbar?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode, debugging, key-value-coding

I get this error when I try to run my app:

```
2010-04-29 13:49:01.355 MyApp[56123:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MyViewController 0x5112b10>
setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for 
the key toolbar.'
```

`MyViewController` used to have an `IBOutlet` called 'toolbar' that connected to a `UIToolbar` object in a nib. I decided I no longer needed the toolbar or the nib so I removed them from the project. But Xcode seems to still want to refer to 'toolbar'.

Where might the reference to toolbar be if I no longer use a nib? I can synthesize a dummy 'toolbar' property to appease Xcode, but I want to avoid this kind of ugly hack.

**EDIT**: Strangely, the exception was not raised when I ran the code on the device rather than the simulator. Also, when I use a trivial nib for `MyViewController` (which contained no toolbar), the exception went away. I am using git and when I went back to run previous commits of my code from before `MyViewController` even had a toolbar or a nib, those strangely gave the exception as well. That code used to run fine. I do think this exception has something to do with Xcode and the simulator and some kind of left over state from when I removed the unwanted nib from the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode is an IDE. It's not Xcode that's asking your view controller for a toolbar while your app is running.

There are two ways to troubleshoot this:

1. Set a breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw`, then run your app under the debugger.
2. Set a breakpoint on `-[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:]`, then run your app under the debugger.

Either way, the debugger will break (interrupt) your app when the exception happens. Look at the stack trace to see what sent the `valueForKey:` message.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I will do this, but how do I set these breakpoints? I don't call these functions explicitly in my code.